# Chaining filters in an ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I had a large list I needed to bind in an `ng-repeat` and the performance was terrible, so I found this link:

http://tech.small-improvements.com/2013/09/10/angularjs-performance-with-large-lists/

And implemented the same pagination they did using their custom `startFrom` filter:

```
angular.module('myApp').filter('startFrom', function () {
    return function (input, start) {
        if (input) {
            return input.slice(start);
        }
    };
});
```

This improved performance to the point where it's acceptable, but it breaks the previous filtering I was doing. Now if I want to search for an item, it'll only work if I'm on the page that contains that item. My understanding was that filters *should* be chainable, but if I do this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="r in foo| filter:query:strict | startFrom: currentPage * pageSize | 
    limitTo:pageSize | orderBy:['type','code']">
```

It appears that the `orderBy` is applied first, then `startFrom` and only finally the `filter`. I originally had `filter` after `startFrom` with the same result. So how can I make this only apply the `startFrom` *after* first applying `filter`?

Comment: `currentPage * pageSize` probably don't update when `query` does.

Comment: @ExplosionPills: That would make a lot of sense. I guess I need a `$watch`.

Comment: @ExplosionPills: Actually, that was exactly it. I put a watch on my `query` to reset `currentPage` to `0` when the filter changed and it works. If you feel like adding an answer to that effect, I'll accept it.

Comment: I get the feeling that would still be very inefficient, but if it works then that is great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can imagine that `currentPage * pageSize` returns some value like 10.  This means that the first 10 items will be skipped even if your filter applies to them.  The `startFrom` filter would have to update to the 0th page when the search changes to include starting items.

You could do this by watching for a change to `query` and resetting the page so you can display the earlier values of the array.